Callback function is not available with promise clients
Here is a function that I'm trying to execute:
loginPW(callback) {
  connection.query('SELECT card_pin FROM card', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      callback(error)
    } else {
      const cardPin = results[0].card_pin;
      const loginArray = [cardPin];
      callback(null, loginArray);
    }
  })
},

I don't understand the error that I'm getting. I tried to take callbacks out of the function and replace them with simple res.status.json's and return statements
Here is my database.js file:
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const connection = mysql.createPool(process.env.MYSQL_SERVER);
module.exports = connection;

And here is the error:
Error: Callback function is not available with promise clients.
at PromisePool.query (C:\restAPI\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:358:13)
at Object.loginPW (C:\restAPI\routeFuncs.js:9:18)
at C:\restAPI\routes\balance.js:10:11
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\restAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5):5)
at next (C:\restAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
at C:\restAPI\jwtAuth.js:18:9
at C:\restAPI\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:261:12
at getSecret (C:\restAPI\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:97:14)
at module.exports [as verify] (C:\restAPI\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:101:10)      
at auth (C:\restAPI\jwtAuth.js:12:9)


"I tried to take callbacks out of the function and replace them with simple res.status.json's and return statements" What did that look like? Because that's what the error is telling you to use: Use the promise the call returns, rather than passing in a callback.

The error is telling you  that .query() does not accept that callback function you're passing in, the => function with (error, response) as the argument list. You should be using it in an async function with await to handle the result, in a try block in case an exception is thrown.
